# Cassandra Docker container does not join cluster in swarm mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, cassandra, docker-compose

I have a Cassandra cluster running in a docker swarm in AWS:

[image]

In this example I have a two-node cluster, but I have been able to reproduce this problem with a larger cluster.

In the compose file used to deploy this cluster, Cassandra's stack mode is set to global so that when a new node joins the swarm, a new Cassandra container is deployed automatically in it.

Unfortunately, often when I join a new node to the swarm the novel cassandra container does not join the Cassandra cluster and it starts its own cluster:

[image]

If I remove/join this node over and over eventually it will join the cluster, but I was wondering what is the cause for this issue and whether there is a way to prevent it.

Thank you for your attention.

**Update**

Cassandra's stack in the yaml file:

```
cassandra:
    image: imageregistry:443/mygroup/cassandra
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.host_role == my_label]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
        gelf-address: "udp://localhost:12201"
    environment:
      - LOGGING_LEVEL=WARN
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 100000
        hard: 100000
    volumes:
      - "/var/lib/cassandra/cassandra-data:/var/lib/cassandra-data"
      - "/var/lib/cassandra/cassandra-commitlog:/var/lib/cassandra-commitlog"
    networks:
      mylan:
        aliases:
          - cassandra
```

Comment: The only people who could answer this question need to know Swarm and Cassandra. Maybe if you give details of how Cassandra discovers its other nodes on a subnet, I can help you with the Swarm part. It would also help to detail versions of docker and cassandra, your stack yaml, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you give your stack file. These things to check with are CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch, CASSANDRA_DC need to be same for all the node to join in same datacenter, Is your cluster name same. If these all are set let me know the logs.

Comment: Is there any subnet created for ec2 instances? then run the cassnadra nodes under same subnet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added Cassandra's stack.